# Inverse Distance Weighted (IDW) Interpolation with Radial Basis Function (RBF) in R

Tags: raster, r, interpolation, inverse-distance-weighted

I want to perform an IDW interpolation with R. I am aware that I can do that with gstat::idw. But I want to change the parameter 'idp' with a radial basis function (RBF):

[image: formula]   where [image: condition]

[image: dist] is the euclidean distance between of the i-th reference point and the j-th grid cell.

Do you know how I can implement this into the function of gstat::idw. Or do you know a script for IDW in R that I could edit?

Answer (score 3):

I believe that you can specify an IDW with a radial basis function in the [geosptdb](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/geosptdb/geosptdb.pdf) library using the "rbfST" funciton. The package is intended for spatial-temporal IDW but should run with a single temporal dimension. This is at least a good place to start and you may be able to modify the "rbfST" function to suit your specific needs.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! this function could be the solution. Unfortunately I couldn't make the function run so far. I don't have multiple temporal dimensions just a SpatialPointsDataFrame with one attribute that shall be interpolated. If I forward the same parameter inputs like for gstat::idw I got an error: "Error `[.data.frame`(x@data, i, j, ..., drop = FALSE) : undefined columns selected". Eventually this is due to a wrong structure of the input values. Do you know how the input data and output data (newdata) should be structured?